# What is PARTUUID from blkid when using msdos partition table?

Tags: partition, gpt, parted, partition-table, sfdisk

I use msdos partition table, so there is no PARTUUID supported (it's only on GPT partition tables)

```
root@xenial:~# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 200 GiB, 214748364800 bytes, 419430400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xa9ff83af

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 314574847 314572800  150G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       314574848 315598847   1024000  500M 83 Linux
/dev/sda3       315598848 399484927  83886080   40G 83 Linux
/dev/sda4       399486974 407875583   8388610    4G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       399486976 407875583   8388608    4G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

So what is PARTUUID displayed in blkid ?

```
root@xenial:~# blkid
/dev/sda1: LABEL="windows" UUID="3364EC1A72AE6339" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="a9ff83af-01"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="/boot" UUID="9de57715-5090-4fe1-bb45-68674e5fd32c" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="a9ff83af-02"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="/" UUID="553912bf-82f3-450a-b559-89caf1b8a145" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="a9ff83af-03"
/dev/sda5: LABEL="SWAP-sda5" UUID="12e4fe69-c8c2-4c93-86b6-7d6a86fdcb2b" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="a9ff83af-05"
```

I need to change it to debug a ubuntu kickstart multiboot installation, where can i set this PARTUUID ?

Comment: Kernel source code documentation for PARTUUID is here: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/init/do_mounts.c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the PARTUUID on a MBR-partitioned disk is the Windows Disk Signature from the MBR block (8 hex digits) + a dash + a two-digit partition number.

The Windows Disk Signature is stored in locations 0x1B8..0x1BB in the first block of the disk (the MBR block), in little-endian byte order.

This command will display the Windows Disk Signature straight out of the MBR:

```
# dd if=/dev/sda bs=1 count=4 skip=440 2>/dev/null | od -t x4 -An
```

Comment: thx ! my source problem is that ubuntu kickstart install break win7 boot. The only thing that change during install are 0>446, and PARTUUID in blkid. I don't want to backup 440>444 with dd then restore it, this would be a dirty fix.
Here is my kickstart file -> https://ptpb.pw/ZMPl
Here my tests -> https://ptpb.pw/Uc7_.png
And here log of win7 cdrom repair tool -> https://ptpb.pw/fxvz
Why is kickstart renewing that PARTUUID but only grub-install doesn't ?

Comment: Your kickstart has `zerombr yes`. It does exactly what you tell it to do, and zeroes the entire MBR block, destroying the old disk signature.

Comment: I talked on IRC with ubuntu kickstart dev, on ubuntu implementation, zerombr does nothing, he pasted me that -> https://paste.ubuntu.com/26409694/
Option is still needed to make unattended kickstart install but that's all.

Just found that i can't set disk_identifier (PARTUUID) with sfdisk, so i will test this (waiting for Win7 to redeploy). Changes are that i backup previous disk_id with sfdisk, and then restore it while creating part table :
https://ptpb.pw/Byx3

Comment: Oh. That's... an interesting choice, but maybe reasonable given that they've merged RedHat Kickstart and Debian `partman` together. Interestingly, on `sfdisk` of Debian 9, the disk signature is known as `label-id`.

Comment: can't correct anymore, but i wanted to say "i can set disk..." not "can't" :) i will tell you if it worked asap.

Comment: sfdisk label-id did the trick ! thx again